# URL pattern of a web application running on TOMCAT 7

Tags: url, jsf, tomcat7, breadcrumbs

I am having a simple web application which has some static pages. The URL which comes in the browser address bar simply depends on file location in the project. 
`http://computername:8080/mylogin/ is my home URL.`

And below are the few URLs which come when I make a single click on the main home page.

```
http://computername:8080/mylogin/ssis/api.jsf
http://computername:8080/mylogin/ssis/dev.jsf
```

I am implementing a breadcrumb. And to generate it I am using javascript by Justin Whitford.
**Issue is** this breadcrumb uses the browser URL to generate it. So my URL should be in some common fashion/pattern to have breadcrumb implemented properly.

I want to control these URLs. I want to make them like this.
Home: `http://myLogin/`

sub pages:

```
http://mylogin/ssis/api/
http://mylogin/ssis/dev/
```

All this I want to have a proper implementation of breadcrumbs.

Comment: *Issue is this breadcrumb uses the browser URL to generate it* Why exactly is that a problem?

Comment: @BalusC: I mention breadcrumb as a context of question. So I have to register a domain name in Tomcat. I have 1 more thing to ask is , how to change the url 'http://mylogin/ssis/dev.jsf' to look like 'http://mylogin/ssis/dev/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy your webapp to the context root by deleting Tomcat's default `/webapps/ROOT` folder altogether and renaming your webapp's `mylogin.war` file to `ROOT.war`.

This way you have http://computername:8080/

You can get rid of port `8080` by configuring Tomcat to listen on default HTTP port `80`. Open Tomcat's `/conf/server.xml`, locate the `<Connector port="8080">` element and edit the port in there.

Now you have http://computername/

You can change the computer name in platform properties or to add a forward in your [hosts config file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29). On Windows, it's the `system32/drivers/etc/hosts` file. Just add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 mylogin
```

Now you have http://mylogin/ (note that this works for local environment only!)

As to mapping the individual pages such as `/foo.jsf` on `/foo`, you could use a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) for this. It's a pretty tedious job. Instead of reinventing the wheel you may want to take a look at [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/).

---

It's only beyond me how exactly changing the hostname, port and context name is related to generating breadcrumbs. You might be exaggerating the concrete problem or using it the wrong way.